# getopts for Windows batch files?

Tags: batch-file, getopts

Is there an easy way to detect options/switches passed in to a batch file via the command line? I'm looking for something along the lines of `sh`'s and `bash`'s [`getopts`](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

<sub>(The batchfile only sees %0, %1, %2, etc. and %*, plus [variations such as %~d0, %~f1, %~x2 etc.](https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command/173169#173169))</sub>

Comment: After reading the superuser question you posted in your answer, that made me think to check robvanderwoude.com and I didn't find anything... if there were an easy way to do it, it would be on http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php. Thanks.